# Reference equality behavior in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
var myObject = new Object();
var myObjectCopy = myObject;

myObject.Name = 'alav';

// logs Name alav on both variable
console.log(myObject, myObjectCopy);

myObject = null;

// logs only myObject as null and myObjectCopy still has name 'alav'
console.log(myObject, myObjectCopy);
```

Why myObjectCopy not become null when they both are reference equal.

Comment: Because setting `myObject` to `null` does not change the value of the `myObjectCopy` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are setting `myObject` to reference `null`. `myObjectCopy`'s will still reference the object you created. For example:

```
var a = [0], b = a;
a = [3];
alert(b); //still 0, only a's reference has been changed
```

Here is a visualization:

Before the assignment

```
old ----> {object} <---- new
```

After

```
old       {object} <---- new
 |
\_/
null
```

Changing `Name` will change it for both objects because you are altering the `{object}` part of the visualization above.

Comment: As a c# programmer, this is something that I cant understand.

Comment: @Al.Net okay, so before the assignment you have `old -> {...} <- copy`, and after `old -> null, copy -> {...}`

Comment: In C#, this behavior will happen only when I do passing copy by value . So i am wondering about thos

Comment: @Al.Net JavaScript is not C#.

Comment: @Al.Net in C# are same rules... when you create `myObjectCopy` and assign `myObject`, actually you just create new copy of `"RValue"` or reference and assign it to `myObjectCopy`, and when you assign `myObject` to null, you just create new value for `myObject`... for more info [LValues and RValues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-value_(computer_science))

Comment: Thanks @Givi, I don't know C# `:P`

Comment: @Givi You opened my eyes!!

Comment: @Doorknob had similar kinda doubt. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761446/javascript-reference-behavior-for-property-of-an-object

Answer (score 2):

Setting a variable (or an object property) to a different value only affects that variable, and never the previously referenced object. Think of it as setting a pointer to a different address.

Comment: I'm not familiar with C#, but I had the impression you could do something similar with C pointers. You can also think of variables as file-system symbolic links (or shortcuts). Setting a new value only redirects the link to a different file. And you don't have access to "locations". You can't delete objects, or change their type.