# Reference behavior for property of an object

Tags: javascript

```
var myObject = new Object();
var myObjectCopy = myObject;

myObject.Name = 'alav';

// logs Name alav on both variable
console.log(myObject, myObjectCopy);

myObject = null;

// logs myObject as null and myObjectCopy still has name 'alav' -> bcoz of reference copy
console.log(myObject, myObjectCopy);
```

The same behavior is not getting replicated below.

```
var objA = {property: 'value'};
var pointer1 = objA;

// update the objA.property, and all references (pointer1 & pointer2) are updated
objA.property = pointer1.property;
objA.property= null;
// logs 'null null' because objA, pointer1 all reference the same object
console.log(objA.property, pointer1.property);
```

Why the above reference copy behavior is not applicable to inner properties(property here) of an object?

objA.property = pointer1.property; -> aren't reference COPY?

Comment: you realize that `var myObjectCopy = myObject;` doesn't really copy anything, it's just two references to the exact same object ?

Comment: And to at the answers, there's no such thing as a "json object", JSON is a dataformat with keys and values normally doublequoted, a regular javascript object is in no way JSON.

Comment: @adeneo To be exact, JSON object exists, it's the native JS object having `stringify()` and `parse()` methods ; ).

Comment: No they do not, those methods creates an object from a valid JSON string, or a valid JSON string from an object, there's no such thing as a "JSON object".

Comment: @Teemu You should've maybe started with the link to the docs instead of an unclear prose description. And it's not being exact as much as it's being pedantic without relevance to the context. It is *absolutely* clear the OP isn't talking about the `JSON` object which is a namespace for json parsing functions in Javascript, so why derail things with hairsplitting?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Are you asking why the two code snippets show different output? Because you do different things! Or what is your actual question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case one you were setting reference to null therefore no change in actual object

```
myObject = null;// setting reference to null object , but no change in actual object
```

In second case you are making changes into the object(changing state of object) 
by setting property to null

```
objA.property = null;
```

hence in every reference , value of property will be null

[image]

Comment: But I am not bit convinced :(

Comment: How did you prepare this chart? using visio?

Comment: try to run the two examples with object / JSON respectively. They will act precisely the same! The difference now is that it is two different piece of code, not a reference issue.

Comment: Thanks david Let me do that